# Is there a Halbach array equivalent for a coil?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

Is there is a way that a coil can have one side of strong alternating field and the other side a weak alternating field? I was planning to use this and see if the efficiency of a coupled coil can become more efficient. So, it ends up combining resonance inductive coupling and a certain arrangement that makes one side of the alternating electromagnetic field stronger.

Comment: Wouldn't an array of coils do what you want?  The windings would have to be creatively constructed, but ...

Comment: @garyp Do you have any ideas for this sir? I would really appreciate your help :)

Comment: The only thing I was thinking of is a Halbach array, except replacing the permanent magnets with small electromagnets.   Of course, they would have to be mounted in the correct orientation, and the mounting would have to be able to withstand the stress.  Perhaps the assembly could be potted.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thought and was looking around to see if anyone has tried it. Thinking about induction motors and replacing permanent magnets with induction electromagnetic coils and a halbach array might be the most efficient I was just uncertain about how to wind copper coils to achieve this. Perhaps twisted around a steel wire in 3 phases.